# O que deve ser retornado na mensagem WM_CREATE para indicar erro?

Tags: winapi

Estou enviando a mensagem `WM_SETFONT` para cada controle para definir a fonte dos mesmos e estou usando a função `CreateFont` para criar a fonte. A função `CreateFont` é chamada quando a mensagem `WM_CREATE` é recebida.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_CREATE: {
            int nHeight = -MulDiv(10, GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(hWnd), LOGPIXELSY), 72);

            SegoeUI = CreateFont(
                nHeight, 0,
                0, 0,
                FW_NORMAL,
                FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
                DEFAULT_CHARSET,
                OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
                DEFAULT_QUALITY,
                DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE,
                _T("Segoe UI")
            );

            if (!SegoeUI) return -1;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Se a função `CreateFont` falhar ela vai retornar `NULL` e se a fonte for `NULL` eu retorno -1 na mensagem `WM_CREATE`. O problema é que não estou conseguindo interromper a criação da janela.

A Microsoft diz o seguinte sobre a mensagem `WM_CREATE`:

> If an application processes this message, it should return zero to continue creation of the window. If the application returns –1, the window is destroyed and the CreateWindowEx or CreateWindow function returns a NULL handle.

A função `CreateWindow` devia retornar `NULL` e eu devia conseguir verificar se a janela foi criada ou não, mas parece que o código é interrompido.

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
    szClassName,
    szTitle,
    dwStyle,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL
);

// daqui para baixo nada é executado

if (!hWnd) { // eu quero fazer essa verificação antes de encerrar
    MessageBox(
        NULL,
        _T("Não foi possível iniciar o programa!"),
        szTitle,
        MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não está conseguindo verificar se a janela foi criada ou não porque, em `WM_CREATE`, depois de verificar se a fonte é `NULL`, deveria retornar -1 caso fosse **OU** 0 (ou simplesmente `DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)`). Como não existe nenhum `break`ou retorno no final, está sendo executado o `case WM_DESTROY`, interrompendo o seu código.

Corrija da seguinte forma:

```
case WM_CREATE: {
            int nHeight = -MulDiv(10, GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(hWnd), LOGPIXELSY), 72);

            SegoeUI = CreateFont(
                nHeight, 0,
                0, 0,
                FW_NORMAL,
                FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
                DEFAULT_CHARSET,
                OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
                DEFAULT_QUALITY,
                DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE,
                _T("Segoe UI")
            );

            if (!SegoeUI) return -1;
            else return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

        }
```